# Google Analytics used for SaaS website behind login

Tags: analytics, google-analytics, saas

Is Google Analytics a good way to track page hits even if the website is a SaaS website behind a login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google analytics runs client side through javascript.  A website is a website is a website, regardless of whether its a distributed system, a single hosted server or a SaaS.

When a user visits the website, the client side javascript is executed which notifies google analytics of an update.  It would work just fine if google analytics provides the type of analysis you want for your system.

Comment: Possibly worth a mention: You'll need to set up *something* public for GA to pull down a copy of your tracking code from before activity on the profile is recorded.